# Problem with a conditional because the result is always the else if

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a simple program where there are 5 die rolls, and whichever one has the biggest number at the end wins, the problem is the if/else if, because the only outcome that's showing is the else if one, even though it should be randomized

I've tried not setting the variables to 0 in the beginning, switching the places up.

```
function RollDie() {

  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
}

var player1 = 0;
var player2 = 0;

player1 = RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie();
player2 = RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie();

if (player2 > player1) {
  text("player 2 has won", 180, 100);
} else if (player2 < player1) {
  text("player 1 has won", 180, 100);
}
```

I expect the final result to be random but it isn't. It's always the if option

Comment: `console.log(RollDie())` will clearly show you your problem

Comment: `RollDie` doesn't return anything, hence players get value of `undefinedundefined...`

Comment: Learn to use console and set break points and inspect the variables.

Answer (score 1):

You need a little bit of adjustment. Just return the dice roll value. It works I checked it.

```
function RollDie() {
  Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
  var diceRoll = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  return diceRoll;
}
var player1 = 0;
var player2 = 0;

player1 = RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie();
player2 = RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie();
if (player2 > player1) {
  alert('player 2 has won', 180, 100);
} else if (player2 < player1) {
  alert('player 1 has won', 180, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the random value.

If you take a function without [`return` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return), the function returns `undefined` by default.

This value is taken for addition and by adding `undefined`, this value is converted to a number, but this failed and you get the value [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), which means, you get a number which is *not a number*. The addition of any number with `NaN` returns `NaN`, the value which you got for both players.

In the condition, a comparison with `NaN` and a value is always `false` hence you got never a winning message.

```js
function RollDie() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    // ^^^
}

var player1 = 0;
var player2 = 0;

player1 = RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie();
player2 = RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie() + RollDie();

console.log(player1);
console.log(player2);

if (player2 > player1) {
    console.log("player 2 has won");
} else if (player2 < player1) {
    console.log("player 1 has won");
}

console.log(undefined + undefined); // NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, although can you explain exactly what that code does I'm confused.

Comment: what is the part you are confused about?

Comment: the "return Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;"